# How to get Received & Sent Network Bytes per second For a process (input: process id or handle) in C++ for Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I need to get network information per process just like in resource monitor. I need to find the received bytes/s & sent bytes/s.

I tried to get it using Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process class. But it gives IO, file bytes in addition to network details.

I tried to get details using Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface class. But it gives details per Network interface.

Then I tried to use GetTcpStatistics function. For that MIB_IPSTATS has been used. MIB_IPSTATS shows cumulative results for entire process.

1. Are there any other MIB Structures to show these details per process manner?
2. how to get Bytes/s thing per process just like in resource monitor which is shown in Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface as cumulated data for entire processes
3. Can I calculate Bytes/s using Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process class based on other values?
4. Are there any methods like GetProcessMemoryInfo ( this method is to get process memory) to get received and sent bytes per sec?
5. Are there any other methods to calculate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try looking into Performance Counters.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373083(v=vs.85).aspx

Here is a code project example of getting network speed using performance counters.  It is in c# but you should be able to translate to c++.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6259/Monitoring-network-speed'

Comment: Neither of these links are "per process" solutions. Performance counters at a process level only show IO general, and the Code Project C# example is monitoring at a NIC level